# vue meteor on subscription ready hook?

Tags: meteor, vue.js

I use meteor vue to subcribe to a publication:

```
 meteor: {
        $subscribe: {
            'gps': function() { return [ this.query ] }
        }
    },
```

The docs only offer the following option:

```
<div v-if="!$subReady.thread">Loading...</div>
```

However, I need to execute some code when the subscription is ready. Is there some kind of onSubscriptionReady hook?

Answer (score 0):

If you use data from the subscription in your template, you can do something like:

```
beforeUpdate() {
  if (this.$subReady['gps']) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I do it this way in my app and so far it works fine. The problem is when you don't use data in the template because update hook isn't fired.